# Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "env" does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, fatal-error, laravel-artisan

After lunching the command `php artisan optimize` , i got

> fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "env" does not exist

I have tried deleting the bootstrap/cache/ and runing `composer update` but nothing works,
everytime i tried to run a **php artisan command/composer command**  i got the same problem. am really stuck. any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear **cache** using:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

**Or** only clear **config cache** using:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

https://dev.to/kenfai/laravel-artisan-cache-commands-explained-41e1

Comment: That what caused the problem. i has to be some typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have something wrong in your config/database.php file. If it is the case when you run **composer update** the console will show some error at the end of execution due the config/database.php file